# How to Load xml file in native(.cpp file) using android

Tags: java, android, c++, xml

I was trying to load xml file in native .cpp file. I pass a filepath from java to cpp, path of the file cannot be loaded.

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lbpcascade_frontalface);
File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
String path = mCascadeFile.toString();
Log.i("TAG", mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
FaceDetector.sample(m, 1,path); //native call
```

In my .cpp file contains

```
FaceDetector::FaceDetector(std::string stdFileName)
{
    cv::CascadeClassifier face_cascade;

    const char* x = stdFileName.c_str();
    face_cascade.load(x);
    LOGD("String value %s",x);

    if (!face_cascade.empty())
    {
        LOGD("Xml loaded Successfully");
    }
    else 
    {
        LOGD("XML not LOADED");
    }
}
```

Xml cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime xml cannot be loaded while content of the path become empty

```
 InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.haarcascade_frontalface_alt);
FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        try {
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
```

Check before to load a xml.

Answer (score 0):

Does x point to a valid (absolute) path?
Is the file x points to a valid xml?

Comment: i get string path from stdFileName , in that i assign a value to const char* x.

Comment: stdFileName becomes something like data/data/app_cascade/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml

Comment: Can you open the file normally from java (with read external storage permission)? If yes, I would guess the format is not valid classifier.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i cannot understand what you ask. can you explain clearly. Normally we can read file from java , in Manifest.xml have read storage permission

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, why xml not loaded. I did a mistake in android.mk file.  i did not include opencv latest version 3.0.0.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include /Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-3.0.0-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_MODULE    := FaceDetectorFile
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := FaceDetector_wrap.cpp FaceDetector.cpp Main.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```